# Can i submit ipad app on appstore only with landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

App is a **just eat** type of application for ordering food.

Comment: Yes, why do you think you wouldn't be able to do this? Just untick the portrait orientation options.

Comment: I just want to know that apple has some guidelines to support both orientations or not?

Comment: I checked this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1588/_index.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple doesn't put any restrictions on specific orientation. It is purely dependent on the App requirement & flow.

So doesn't matter if Application is for only with Landscape orientation or only with Portrait applications.

If it is according to the apple guidelines than they will approve it. Doesn't matter which orientation App supports.

Comment: okay, this note is written on apple Technical questions link "It is strongly recommended that your iPad applications support all orientations. This includes portrait, portrait upside-down, landscape left and landscape right. iPad apps that require an orientation must support both variants of that orientation".... That's why i asked this question

Comment: @Divyu as you said its written on technical questions, you can view apps on iTunes exists with only Landscape orientation. :)

Comment: @Divyu by "both variants" it means if it supports Landscape, it must support Landscape left and landscape right. If it supports Portrait, then it must support Portrait and portrait upside down.

Comment: you can refer to this document. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1588/_index.html

Comment: It is mandatory as of Aug 2018 https://imgur.com/yYFGUh9

Comment: @SoftDesigner right i faced the same issue. It says to support multitasking feature you need to support all layout orientations.